# Find when $f(x) = g(x)$ if I know when $f^2(x) = g^2(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose I want to find the values of $x$ for which $f(x) = g(x)$. Suppose it is difficult, but easy to do it for $f(x)^2 = g(x)^2$. As I understand if for some $x$, $f^2(x) = g^2(x)$, it doesn't mean that $f(x) = g(x)$.

So what should I do in this situation, put all $x$'s that I've found in the equation $f(x) = g(x)$, and see if this is true?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)^2$ or $f(f(x))$?

Comment: @Hurkyl: The former. I didn't know the place of $2$ matters.

Comment: It's an awkward ambiguity: both meanings (exponentiation or repeated composition) are commonly used, although I think the composition meaning is more common except in special cases like the trig functions. Confusingly, which meaning is meant can change depending on the number; e.g. $\sin^2(x)$ usually means $\sin(x)^2$, but $\sin^{-1}(x)$ usually means $\arcsin(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ are real-valued functions of a real variable, the places where $f^2(x)=g^2(x)$ are precisely the places where the magnitudes of the two functions are equal, i.e. $|f(x)|=|g(x)|$. (To see this, take the square root of both sides).

Once you have solved for the set of all $x$ where the functions' magnitudes are equal, it remains to throw out the $x$es where $f(x)=-g(x)$ and $f(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: Leave those $x$es in. (corrected in answer)